# Deadlock when dispatching notification in notification handler using Poco::NotificationCenter

Tags: c++, deadlock, poco-libraries, notificationcenter

I'm using Poco as part of a C++ app and I've run into an issue I don't quite understand. The app was translated from Obj-C and made heavy use of Apple's NSNotificationCenter.

To make the transition as painless as possible, I decided to use Poco's NotificationCenter instead. It works fine but I had some users reporting deadlocks I'm now trying to resolve.

Just a quick heads-up for those not familiar with NotificationCenter. You signup for a notification like this:

```
Poco::NotificationCenter& nc = Poco::NotificationCenter::defaultCenter();
nc.addObserver(Poco::NObserver<MyClass, MyNotification>(*this, &MyClass::onNotification));
```

and post a notification like this:

```
Poco::NotificationCenter& nc = Poco::NotificationCenter::defaultCenter();
nc.postNotification(new MyNotification());
```

The postNotification() method is defined like this:

```
void NotificationCenter::postNotification(Notification::Ptr pNotification)
{
    poco_check_ptr (pNotification);

    ScopedLockWithUnlock<Mutex> lock(_mutex);
    ObserverList observersToNotify(_observers);
    lock.unlock();
    for (ObserverList::iterator it = observersToNotify.begin(); it != observersToNotify.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->notify(pNotification);
    }
}
```

And NObserver::notify() like this:

```
void notify(Notification* pNf) const
{
    Poco::Mutex::ScopedLock lock(_mutex);

    if (_pObject)
    {
        N* pCastNf = dynamic_cast<N*>(pNf);
        if (pCastNf)
        {
            NotificationPtr ptr(pCastNf, true);
            (_pObject->*_method)(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

This is all really simple and doesn't involve any black magic.

Given the fact that the postNotification method always iterates over all observers (AFTER locking one and before checking if the type of the notification matches using a dynamic typecast) I'm assuming that this MUST always cause a deadlock when a notification is sent from a notification handler as it would also try to access the observer where itself is called from and will wait forever on the lock in NObserver::notify()?
From the process samples my users sent me it looks like my assumption is correct.

But for some reason this doesn't appear to deadlock in most cases (I never experienced it ever myself). I just stepped through with the debugger and couldn't make it lock up. Does anyone have an explanation why this only locks up under **certain** circumstances?

Comment: Im expericing the exact same issue, today I was able to figure it out. Given the lock before the type check, the order where the NObservers were added has implications on the execution itself. Iwill try to make up a test case and report it. Possibly I will solve it creating my own NObserver with the lock after the type check

Comment: Created issue
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2581#issuecomment-572940956
Please, add, comment, upvote it so we may get an expert answer